# ViewExpiredException in JSF while upgrading Tomcat on cluster

Tags: jsf, tomcat

I upgraded a Tomcat 7.0.27 to Tomcat 7.0.57 and the Tomcat is in cluster environment. After upgraded, the Tomcat in cluster, we are getting `ViewExpiredException`, didn't get in previous version in cluster.

1. Added state saving method to client but still not working

   ```
   <context-param>
       <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
       <param-value>server</param-value>
   </context-param>
   ```
2. Tried by using error-page tag

   ```
   <error-page>
       <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
       <location>/faces/login.xhtml</location>
   </error-page>
   ```

It's also not working.

If, when we stopped any one of the server, it's working fine. when ever we bring up the another server getting this issue and the first time only getting this issue, if we reloaded the page, it's working fine.

Strange is, code working fine in Tomcat 7.0.27,

Any suggestions please.

Comment: Here, I missed one point, what ever the link I clicked on the page, it will makes an ajax call,

Comment: Looks like a problem with session replication.

Comment: Couple of things to you verify: 1- Check if the new version of the tomcat has already an embedded JSF version on the lib folder; 2 - How are you managing the tomcat cluster?